# Error Converting String to Date in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

Hi I get the below error when I try to execute the below code:

```
date_input= '2015-01-25'
date_parameter=$(date -d `echo $date_input` +%s)

min_date=$(date -d 2015-11-01 +%s)
max_date=$(date -d $(date +"%Y-%m-%d") +%s)

if [ "$date_parameter" -gt "$max_date" ] || [ "$date_parameter" -lt "$min_date" ]; then
```

Error ->   [: : integer expression expected

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix your script by using:

```
date_input='2015-01-25'
date_parameter=$(date -d "$date_input" '+%s')
min_date=$(date -d 2015-11-01 '+%s')
max_date=$(date '+%s')

[[ $date_parameter -gt $max_date || $date_parameter -lt $min_date ]] &&
  echo "ok" || echo "nope"
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove whitespace after `=` in first line.

Comment: date_input=$1
Its actually a input parameter to the script